# Debug file with arbitrary file extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates

I'm working on a C++ program in Visual Studio 2010. The program I'm working on uses a few template classes. The template implementations are located in `.tpp` files (it could be any other arbitrary file extension).

Visual Studio's syntax highlighting goes away when displaying the `.tpp` files. Additionally, the "DataTips" do not work (hover over a variable that is in scope to see its value).

Is there a way to enable syntax highlighting? And can I enable "DataTips"?

The Watch and other debug windows still work, but aren't as convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2010 for unknown file types:

1. `Tools` -> `Options...`
2. `Text Editor` -> `File Extension`
3. Add extension `tpp` for editor `Microsoft Visual C++`
4. Click `OK`